# Typescript wrapper for console.log with variable number of arguments

Tags: typescript

I want to create a wrapper in TypeScript around console.log like this:

```
var mylog = (...args: any[]) => { console.log(args); };
```

So I loglike this:

```
if (!!mylog) mylog('text', variableA, variableB);
```

And can set it to null to disable logging.

Problem is: this doesn't work!

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to not do `if(!!myLog)` and instead set it to an empty function if you want to disable logging?

Comment: @Benjamin: you are right! Much simpler...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine:

```
var mylog = (...args: any[]) => { console.log(args); };

if (!!mylog) mylog('text', 1, 2); // ['text',1,2]

mylog = null; 

if (!!mylog) mylog('text', 1, 2); // nothing printed
```

Perhaps you don't want it to print as an `array`. You can just use `apply`:

```
var mylog = (...args: any[]) => { console.log.apply(console,arguments); };
```

Comment: Basarat, thanks again! You are right, and the console.log.apply saved my day!

Comment: You can also simplify apply with spread syntax: `var mylog = (...args: any[]) => { console.log(...args) }`